# Simple AJAX query in chrome/safari providing not-so-simple debugging situation

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a *very* simple jQuery/ajax script for a membership driven website.  The script just checks to see if the user entered info, validates it against my database and returns 1 for a failed login attempt, and 0 if the username/password match.

The function works perfectly when I run it w/o calling it from ajax.

**Firefox:** everything works.
**Chrome/Safari:** The query is locking everything up.  When I enter valid info, there isn't even any record of a request going out (in the developer tools chrome/safari supply).  When invalid info is entered the request is going out and it returns 3.

I'm pretty baffled by this.

Is it a "sandbox" issue?  as I understand it Firefox and Chrome/safari handle XHR differently... Although don't ask me how.

I am running a base install of [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html).  Could this be something on my developer environment?  (I will be testing it on a live server later this afternoon)

Here is my AJAX call and the php script it is calling.

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  //I've also tried..
  //url: '_modules/php/session.php',
 url: 'http://localhost/current/100TradeJack/httpdocs/_modules/php/session.php',
 type: 'POST',
 cache: false,
 timeout: 5000,
 data: "method=login&"+$('#loginTop').serialize(),
 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
 {
  alert("ERORR!!");
 },
 success: function(response){
  alert(response);
  if(response == '0'){ 
   alert("log user in");
   window.location.replace("http://localhost/current/100TradeJack/httpdocs/trading.php");
  } else if(response == '1') {
   alert("invalid username/password");
  } else {
   alert("ERRROOR!");
  }

 }
});
```

session.php:

```
if($_POST['method'] == 'login'){
    $validated = login($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
    echo $validated;
}


function login($email, $password){
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("sandbox_members", $connection) or die(mysql_error());


if($email){
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
} else {
 return 1;
}

if($password){
 $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
} else {
 return 1;
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='". $email . "' AND password='". $password ."'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 return 0; 
} else {
 return 3;
}

//if it gets to here the username/password combo was incorrect or was not found in the db
return 1;
mysql_close($connection);
}
```

Comment: I'd take even a hint as the accepted answer at this point... lmao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small issue in your **PHP code**:

After your query db, you return some numbers representing state, however on the end of the script you close the connection to your database... **mysql_close($conn)** will never occur as you jump out of the function scope with those various **returns** before the closing statement. Maybe those hiccups you experience are because of unclosed DB connections.

**JS** code looks fine

I modified the ajax call to grab a static html, which I edited to various scenarios (using 0, 1, ...) and it worked perfectly (Opera, Chrome, FF)..

Also try `window.alert($('#loginTop').serialize())` to check posted data, or create a plain html document with a form and JS (without all other logic) and point it to your script.

Also check your scripts for `console.log()` as this may destroy your javascript in other browsers than FF

Comment: You got it - I put mysql_close($conn) in before returning and it worked.  So silly...

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be a sandboxing issue. How are you firing this ajax request? Are you sure that the development console provide no error output (make sure you're not excluding errors).

I don't have a PHP/web dev environment up but you can try some debugging stuff:

- Try setting the url to a domain-relative url: '/current/100TradeJack/httpdocs/_modules/php/session.php'
- Point the login verification URL to a static page with 0 or 1 to test if that works.
- Figure out where chrome and safari "go silent" by putting alerts before this ajax call.

  - Is the event getting fired?
  - Is your function (containing this ajax request) getting called?
  - Is your initialization code getting called?
- Do a plain ajax request which fetches the login verification result (or the static one) and alert the response out. Try onclick or when the page finishes loading.
- If you have a lot of JS code, simplify the problem. Start slashing code out (back it up first), and see if it still (doesn't) work.
- <strike>Blame IE</strike> (whoops). If you're still stumped, you can submit the slashed code up to webkit as a bug. You can also check if it's a confirmed bug there.

Comment: when I return 0 immediately from login() it works properly.  Chrome locks up immediately after the if($row = $result) line.  Ajax works as expected in all other situations I've used it so far... The query is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 return 1;
```

use

```
echo "1";
```

Your calling up the function in ajax and it expects response writeline out in the page

---

Also check your mysql results maybe there is an error in the query that why its routing to

```
else { return 3 };
```

Comment: ah, I lacked to mention that when it is called, I do echo the return...  And when I add else { return 3; } it doesn't return anything.